# Mysql - Get records where column value is everything but a specific value

Tags: mysql, join, select

I have two tables:

Car

Columns:

```
id
```

Wheel

Columns:

```
id | car_id | tire_pressure
```

A car has many wheels.

I want to select all `Car`s that does not have a `Wheel` with the `tire_pressure` of 'low' so it can have many other wheels, but if it does not have a wheel with the `tire_pressure` of 'low' then I would want it to be returned in the query result.

Can this be done in mysql?

Comment: `HAVING SUM(tire_pressure = 'low') = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`!=` operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html), near the top of that linked page.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this if I have the join key correct.

`select a.id, b.car_id, b.tire_pressure from car a
JOIN wheel b on a.id = b.car_id
where b.tire_pressure != 'low';`

Answer (score 0):

You may try below -

```
SELECT DISTINCT car_id
FROM Wheel
WHERE car_id NOT IN (SELECT car_id
                     FROM Wheel
                     WHERE UPPER(tire_pressure) = 'LOW')
```